# In Seamus Heaney's 'North', why are the Vikings' voices "lifted in violence and epiphany"?

Tags: meaning, poetry, seamus-heaney

Seamus Heaney's poem '[North](https://archive.org/details/northpoems0000hean/page/18/mode/2up)' contains these lines:

> those fabulous raiders,
> those lying in Orkney and Dublin […]
> were ocean-deafened voices
> warning me, lifted again
> in **violence and epiphany**.

It would be great if you explain the meaning of the words 'violence' and 'epiphany' in the context of the poem.

Answer (score 4):

The speaker of ‘North’ describes the experience of standing on a beach (“a long strand”) on the Atlantic coast of Ireland (“facing … Iceland [and] Greenland”) and “suddenly” finding himself imagining the Vikings (“those fabulous raiders”) and being inspired by them to write poetry (“lie down in the word-hoard … compose in darkness”).

So in this context the “voices” belong to these imagined Vikings. Their voices were “lifted in violence” when uttering war-cries as they [raided the coastal settlements of Ireland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_Scandinavian_Dublin#Early_Viking_raids) in the ninth and tenth centuries. An “epiphany” is a “sudden manifestation of appearance of some divine or superhuman being” (*OED*), or figuratively, a sudden realization or inspiration. This is a [transferred epithet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypallage): it is really the speaker who is experiencing a sudden inspiration, not the Vikings.